# How to send Push Notification to some users not all?

Tags: apple-push-notifications

Hello friends i am using PushWoosh API http://www.pushwoosh.com for Push Notification implementation and also read http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/WhatAreRemoteNotif/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW1 
But could not find anything related to what i want.

is it possible to send Push Notification only some users?
For example, I want to send notification only those users who have not purchased my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send notifications to specific devices using device tokens in Pushwoosh Remote API, under which each device is registered. You just need to use the "devices" parameter:

```
"devices":["dec301908b9ba8df85e57a58e40f96f523f4c2068674f5fe2ba25cdc250a2a41"],
```

This device push token can be received after the /registerDevice method was called on the device and sent to your server.

However, though iOS device tokens remain the same, Android tends to change them from time to time, so there's no guarantee that your message will reach an Android device.

The most convenient way in Pushwoosh is to use Tags, where you can set a Tag and register each device under this tag with its unique ID or alias. Tags advantage is that they can be used if you want to send your notifications to users who have your app installed on a few devices.

Using Tags, you need to implement it within your app, and then use "filter" or "conditions" parameters in the Remote API request:

```
"conditions": [TAG_CONDITION1, TAG_CONDITION2, ..., TAG_CONDITIONN]

where Tag_condition should look like ["alias", "EQ", "john_smith"]
```

Comment: thanks for response. It seems useful but i am very new to iOS, could not understand what i have to do to integrate Remote API? Is there any guide or steps to follow to integrate Remote API. If you reply i really will be very thankful to you.

Comment: Can you tell me the purpose of Remote API